# unrecognized token '(' in values list, expecting ')'

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert into Oracle Database using JDBC prepared statement. Below is the sql that I am trying to insert.

And everytime I get sql exception for below SQL

```
private static String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO USER_COPY (ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) VALUES ('123456789', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-02-01 12:37:40.315'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-02-01 12:37:40.315'))";
```

**Exception**

```
unrecognized token '(' in values list, expecting ')'
```

**Table Properties**

```
ID is String
CREATION_DATE timestamp
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE timestamp
```

Anything wrong with my SQL?

Comment: Why is therea , at the end?

Comment: I pasted it in a wrong way. Forgot to remove that one. Updated the question now with correct sql.

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes with escaped double qoutes.

Comment: Can you provide me the sql syntax that I need to execute as I was not able to understand what you just mentioned above.

Comment: [Mkyong should help you on prepared statement](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) @Nevzz03

Comment: That error message is unfamiliar; have you got a wrapper around the JDBC calls that is doing its own validation? e.g. (and I'm not saying this is a good idea) trying to detect SQL injection? The whole stack trace might be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if perhaps it's not your timestamp format?  This worked for me using `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_COPY (ID int, CREATION_DATE TimeStamp, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE TimeStamp);

INSERT INTO USER_COPY (ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
VALUES ('123456789',
        TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-02-01 12:37:40.315', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 
        TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-02-01 12:37:40.315', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
        );
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3cbb).

Good luck.